# C++ LinkedList data input

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to run a while loop injecting data into a linkedlist that I've made. When the user enters -1 as a value, the program will stop putting data into the linked list. For some reason, what I have doesn't work and I'm not sure if I understand the logic behind it.

```
class House
{
    public:
        struct node{
            double width;
            double length;
            node *next;
        };

        int houseSize;

        House();
        double calculateTax(double);
};

House::House(){

    //Temporary variables for location and data injecting.
    int temp = 0;
    houseSize = 0;

    //Nodes for both the first location and current location in the linked list.
    node *root; 
    node *conductor;  

    root = new node;
    root->next = 0;

    //Point to the first location.
    conductor = root;

    if (conductor != 0) {
        while (conductor->next != 0){
            houseSize++;

            if(temp != -1){

                //Ask for user input about the rooms.
                cout << "What is the width of room " << houseSize << ": ";
                cin >> temp;    

                if(temp != -1){
                    //If the list isn't ending, input data.
                    conductor->width=temp;  
                }

                //Ask for user input about the rooms.
                cout << "What is the length of room " << houseSize << ": ";
                cin >> temp;    

                if(temp != -1){
                    //If the list isn't ending, input data.
                    conductor->length=temp; 

                    //Point to the next node.
                    conductor->next = new node;
                    conductor = conductor->next;

                }

            }
        }

        //End the linked list to prevent new data from being added.
        conductor->next = new node;  
        conductor = conductor->next;
        conductor->next = 0;       

    }

}
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it?

Comment: I'm getting an exception when I run the object.

Comment: Don't put I/O logic inside the constructor. Don't make the internal structure of the house visible this way. The constructor should just initialize the linked list, and the house should have a function to add a room, given its width and length. Let some external function do the I/O.

Comment: That's how my prof wanted it. All input done in the constructor.

Comment: That's not what this is about, this is about fixing problems. You're derailing my topic.

Comment: Looks like you can also put a width of -1 but length of valid number and have it keep looping.   Then you'll have uninitialize 'width' fields as you don't assign it in the case of width == -1

Comment: Do you know why it does this? I found this problem as well.

Comment: You wrote the code, why don't you act upon the -1 and break out of the loop?   Instead of counting on conductor->next being zero for an exit condition, you should use a boolean variable.    bool done = false;   Then when you get a -1 input you can done=true;    Update the while loop to be based on done.   so... while (!done) {

Answer (score 0):

```
node *root; 
node *conductor;  

root = new node;
root->next = 0;

//Point to the first location.
conductor = root;

if (conductor != 0) {
    while (conductor->next != 0){
        ...
    }//End while

    //End the linked list to prevent new data from being added.
    conductor->next = new node;  
    conductor = conductor->next;
    conductor->next = 0;       

}//End if
```

It looks like conductor is root and root->next is zero, so it will skip your while loop entirely and then at the bottom, assign conductor next to a new node and switch it to be the root.

So, I'm guessing your while loop should be :

```
while (conductor->next == 0) {
```

Once you get into the inner bit, on valid length input, you don't set conductor->next to zero.   Its now a small circular buffer.  Update as follows :

```
                //Point to the next node.
                conductor->next = new node;
                conductor = conductor->next;
                conductor->next = 0;   // ADD THIS!
```

EDIT :
Based on all the comments, I think this is the final solution you are looking for :

```
// Helper method to create a node, set internal pointers and data members to zero.  Should really be node CTOR...
node* allocateNewNode()
{
     node * tmp = new node;
     if (tmp == 0) return 0;
     tmp->width = 0;
     tmp->length = 0;
     tmp->next = 0;
     return tmp;
}

House::House() :
    houseSize(1) 
{

//Temporary variables for location and data injecting.
int temp = 0;

//Nodes for both the first location and current location in the linked list.
node *root = allocateNewNode(); 
node *conductor = root;  

bool done = false;

if (conductor != 0) 
{
    // Conductor points to a new unused node at top of loop.
    while (!done) 
    {

       //Ask for user input about the rooms.
       cout << "What is the width of room " << houseSize+1 << ": ";
       cin >> temp;    

       if(temp != -1) 
       {
            //If the list isn't ending, input data.
            conductor->width = temp;  

            //Ask for user input about the rooms.
            cout << "What is the length of room " << houseSize+1 << ": ";
            cin >> temp;    

            if(temp != -1) 
            {
                //If the list isn't ending, input data.
                conductor->length = temp; 

                //Point to the next node and make things identical to top of loop.
                conductor->next = allocateNewNode();
                conductor = conductor->next;
                ++houseSize;
            }
            else
            {
                done = true;
            }
       }
       else
       {
          done = true;
       }
   }
   // Fell off bottom of list, so done is true and conductor points to an invalid node
   // width MIGHT be set from above, so zero it back out.
   conductor->width = 0;

   // conductor already points to an empty unused node, so there is nothing to do to terminate the linked list
}

}
```

Comment: When I run the loop, -1 doesn't end it. Do you know why?

Comment: Yes.   You need to add the second snippet of code.  When you put -1 width, you take no action.   when you do valid length, you don't set conductor->next to zero to allow loop to continue.  You need to do something when you enter -1, you don't have any code which runs on -1 case to stop the loop.

Comment: I provided the full solution in the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is headed by these lines:

```
if (conductor != 0) {
    while (conductor->next != 0){
```

However, just above that, you set `conductor` to be equal to `root`, and you set `root` to be a newly allocated node, so it's guaranteed to be non-null, so the if-condition is a constant true. You also set `root->next` to `0`, and `conductor->next` is the same thing, so the while-condition is a constant false. In other words, all that code you wrote is guaranteed to never get executed.

I don't know where the exception comes from. You don't throw any exceptions, and you can't "run an object". But note that `root` is a local variable in the constructor, so you never actually save the house layout. Also, you leak all the memory you allocate, and also that which you would allocate if the I/O code was actually executed.

Finally, are you sure your prof wanted "all input done in the constructor", and not something like "the constructor should take as input the list of rooms"?

Comment: "When the House class constructor runs the user is asked to enter in the width and length of each room until they have completed all the rooms.  They can indicate this by entering in a -1 for each width or length.  Data for each of the rooms will be added to the linked list."

Comment: That's exactly what it says in the assignment.

Comment: That makes me sad. :-( Not to mention the incorrect grammar - "for each width or length" is probably meant to say "for either width or length" or "for both width and length".

Comment: I have a new issue. Now when I try to use a member function to manipulate the data stored in the linked list, the list is empty.

Comment: Please post a new question when you have a new problem.